# REST-assured | How to get list of values based on matching critera using JSONpath

Tags: json, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying fetch the list  of values based on the criteria using JSON path REST-assured.

Following is my JSON response and I want to fetch the values for credentialId where credentialType" is "Ban User Name", I tried the below code however its returning null values for me. Can some on please help me with correct JSONpath to fetch the desired values.

```
List<Object> object1 = response1.jsonPath().getList("credentials.findAll { it.credentialType=='Ban User Name' }");


[
    {
        "addresses": [

        ],
        "dateOfBirth": null,
        "credentials": [
            {
                "credentialId": "mregasapgreene",
                "credentialType": "Ban User Name",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            },
            {
                "credentialId": "MGREENE",
                "credentialType": "Ban ID",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            }
        ],
        "dateDeceased": null,
        "emails": [

        ],
        "ethnicity": null,
        "guid": "3b020aed-1c69-469c-889d-301e8abce78c",
        "maritalStatus": null,
        "metadata": {
            "dataOrigin": "GRAILS"
        },
        "names": [
            {
                "firstName": "Mallory",
                "lastName": "(Reg as AP) Greene",
                "middleName": "A",
                "nameType": "Primary",
                "pedigree": null,
                "preferredName": null,
                "lastNamePrefix": null,
                "title": null
            }
        ],
        "phones": [

        ],
        "races": [

        ],
        "roles": [
            {
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null,
                "role": "Student"
            }
        ],
        "gender": null
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "addressType": "Mailing",
                "city": "Seattle",
                "country": null,
                "county": null,
                "region": "WA",
                "streetAddress1": "123 Sesame Street",
                "streetAddress2": null,
                "streetAddress3": null,
                "postalCode": "98199"
            },
            {
                "addressType": "Home",
                "city": "Malvern",
                "country": {
                    "value": "United States of America",
                    "code": "US"
                },
                "county": null,
                "region": "PA",
                "streetAddress1": "412 Two Street",
                "streetAddress2": null,
                "streetAddress3": null,
                "postalCode": "19355"
            }
        ],
        "dateOfBirth": null,
        "credentials": [
            {
                "credentialId": "937",
                "credentialType": "Ban Sourced ID",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            },
            {
                "credentialId": "s11",
                "credentialType": "Ban User Name",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            },
            {
                "credentialId": "025EB9EF4420F0D0E05018958B283255",
                "credentialType": "Ban UDC ID",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            },
            {
                "credentialId": "A00000718",
                "credentialType": "Ban ID",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            }
        ],
        "dateDeceased": null,
        "emails": [

        ],
        "ethnicity": null,
        "guid": "3f86c5e3-08b8-431b-bdc5-3ee250847976",
        "maritalStatus": null,
        "metadata": {
            "dataOrigin": null
        },
        "names": [
            {
                "firstName": "Student",
                "lastName": "101",
                "middleName": null,
                "nameType": "Primary",
                "pedigree": null,
                "preferredName": null,
                "lastNamePrefix": null,
                "title": null
            }
        ],
        "phones": [
            {
                "phoneExtension": null,
                "phoneNumber": "+1 12",
                "phoneType": "Home"
            }
        ],
        "races": [

        ],
        "roles": [
            {
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null,
                "role": "Student"
            }
        ],
        "gender": null
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "addressType": "Mailing",
                "city": "Seattle",
                "country": null,
                "county": null,
                "region": "WA",
                "streetAddress1": "123 Sesame Street",
                "streetAddress2": null,
                "streetAddress3": null,
                "postalCode": "98199"
            }
        ],
        "dateOfBirth": null,
        "credentials": [
            {
                "credentialId": "938",
                "credentialType": "Ban Sourced ID",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            },
            {
                "credentialId": "s12",
                "credentialType": "Ban User Name",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            },
            {
                "credentialId": "025EB9EF5535F0D0E05018958B283255",
                "credentialType": "Ban UDC ID",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            },
            {
                "credentialId": "A00000719",
                "credentialType": "Ban ID",
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null
            }
        ],
        "dateDeceased": null,
        "emails": [
            {
                "emailAddress": "ilpstudent102@test.eln.com",
                "emailType": "Personal",
                "guid": "2a7d3ba4-9ec6-49b3-a3f8-a9e757f756a4"
            },
            {
                "emailAddress": "ilpstudent102@test.eln.com",
                "emailType": "Preferred",
                "guid": "2a7d3ba4-9ec6-49b3-a3f8-a9e757f756a4"
            }
        ],
        "ethnicity": null,
        "guid": "06c93bce-a380-4ff4-83a4-3a92e7cb18db",
        "maritalStatus": null,
        "metadata": {
            "dataOrigin": null
        },
        "names": [
            {
                "firstName": "Student",
                "lastName": "102",
                "middleName": null,
                "nameType": "Primary",
                "pedigree": null,
                "preferredName": null,
                "lastNamePrefix": null,
                "title": null
            }
        ],
        "phones": [

        ],
        "races": [

        ],
        "roles": [
            {
                "effectiveEndDate": null,
                "effectiveStartDate": null,
                "role": "Student"
            }
        ],
        "gender": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following expression worked for me.

```
response1.jsonPath().getList("collect { it.credentials.findAll { it.credentialType == 'Ban User Name'}.credentialId }.flatten()")
```